# SEO advise for WordPress WooCommerce

Tags: seo, wordpress, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I'm using WooCommerce and have selected "shop" page as homepage in WordPress settings. Therefore `http://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com/shop` are one and the same page.

In this case what I should do? Use canonical element in header or 301 redirect?
I have read several things about both, but I'm unable to judge what's perfect for this situation. I'm here to seek some advise from SEO experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "shop" webpage as homepage and if two webpages have the same content, you should apply a 301 redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/shop`. You need to do this to avoid duplicate content.

Moreover, I think it's useless to show two webpages with the same content to your visitors, it's a little bit confusing. That's why you should apply 301 redirect instead of `rel="canonical"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is causing a redirect loop for example.com/shop/myproduct

Comment: Ok you just need to delete the other redirect that causes the problem.

Comment: I placed this in .htacess : `Redirect 301 /shop http://example.com` so there's just one redirect... but it's causing redirect loop for `example.com/shop/myproduct`

Comment: Ok for _.htaccess_ redirects but look at DNS redirects managed on cPanel from your web hosting.

Comment: I get a bit confused about the redirect methods. Ok, 301 redirect with PHP is one possibility, then we have the .htaccess... and furthermore updating the nameservers (or DNS?).

When do I choose which method for what?